# What is the name of the steel guard in this image?

Tags: word-request, image-identification, australian-english

What is the name of the steel guard marked by cross in the below image?

[image: Protective railing]

What is the name of the thing that this bike is locked to?
[image: Small railing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call the first image a *railing*, or a *handrail*.

> - [railing](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/railing)
>     a fencelike barrier composed of one or more horizontal rails supported by widely spaced uprights; balustrade.
> - [handrail](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/handrail)
>     a rail serving as a support or guard at the side of a stairway, platform, etc.
>
> (Dictionary.com)

The second one, I would call it a *rack*, or a *bike rack*. It could also be called a *stand*.

> A bicycle parking rack, usually shortened to bike rack and also called a bicycle stand, is a device to which bicycles can be securely attached for parking purposes.
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_parking_rack))

Wikipedia has a few specific names, like *U-rack*. It says the variant names are *Staple* and *Sheffield rack*.
[image]